# Getting ORA-06532: Subscript outside of limit

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, varray

I have created varray collection type inorder to get a serv_item_id column value from serv_item table. But while executing im getting subsript outside of limit error.

```
declare
type t1 is varray(1000) of serv_item%rowtype;
v_t1 t1:=t1();
n number :=0;
cursor c1 is select * from serv_item;
begin
open c1;
loop
v_t1.extend();
fetch c1 into v_t1(n);
exit when c1%notfound;
n:=n+1;
end loop;
close c1;
for i in 0..v_t1.count
loop
dbms_output.put_line('The serv item'||v_t1(i).serv_item_id);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

varray indexing begins at 1, not 0.